# How to throw an exception in your Extension?

Tags: php, exception, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In an Extbase extension, the need may arise to inform the user about an error or exception.

In my case, I have to parse some data from a potentially bad source. So the extension has to validate this data. And if the data is invalid, it needs to throw an exception that then can be handled by TYPO3.

However, I can only find information about how the exception and error handlers works, but no information on how to correctly throw an exception from inside an extension.

So what is the intended way to throw an exception from inside an Extbase extension?

### Expected result

If I produce a syntax error, TYPO3 displays a message similar to this:
[image]
(Taken from [the core API reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Screenshots/Index.html).)

That is what I would expect a *correctly* thrown error or exception to look like.

### What I tried

Edit: I tried throwing an error like this:

```
throw new \Exception('Invalid data');
```

However, all the frontend displays is

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20160721101726b5339896

Another possible way to produce an error:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit('Invalid data');
```

However, this shows a Page Not Found error instead of the expected exception.

Comment: Why not use the good old http://php.net/manual/de/exception.construct.php or a exception handler plugin?

Comment: @cptnk Sorry, I should have been more detailed. Tried that already, didn't give the expected result. Appended my question.

Comment: Ahhh you probably just have displayErrors in your LocalConfiguration set to hide error messages and store them in the error.log. Now thats behavior you'd probably want. How about using the flashmessanger instead?

Comment: But an syntax error is displayed just as I would expect, like shown in the screenshot.

Comment: syntax errors & exits are diffrent. If your PHP detects a syntax error it stops at that point and prints a error message. Depending on when that happens you could already have the "error style" from typo3 but you may never have been close to your actually typo3 application dealing with errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implicitly asked 2 questions:

1. *How do I correctly throw an exception in my code?*

I think, that was correct, what you did: Just use PHP \Exception or a suitable exception inherited from \Exception:

```
throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Invalid data');
```

2. *Once an exception has been thrown, how do I see more information?*

This has already been answered quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34067853/2444812

**On a development system:**

- set configuration preset "debug"
- Add TypoScript on start page: `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0`

see [Error and ExceptionHandling Example](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Examples/Index.html)

**On a production system:**

You usually do not want to see full stack traces in the frontend. That is why `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler` is usually set to default, which only shows *Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20160721101726b5339896* on the rendered page. Using this code, you can look in the logs (if things are logged and what is logged where always depends on the configuration of the logging system):

- sys_log : see "Log" in the backend
- logfile: var/logs/*.log (see [Logging with TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Logging/Index.html)). May be typo3temp/logs on older versions and typo3temp/var/logs/ on non-Composer systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace VendorName\ExtensionName\Controller;

abstract class ActionController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $entityNotFoundMessage = 'The requested entity could not be found.';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $unknownErrorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred. The wild monkey horde in our basement will try to fix this as soon as possible.';

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     * @override \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
     */
    public function processRequest(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request, \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response) {
        try {
            parent::processRequest($request, $response);
        }
        catch(\Exception $exception) {
            // If the property mapper did throw a \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception, because it was unable to find the requested entity, call the page-not-found handler.
            $previousException = $exception->getPrevious();
            if (($exception instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception) && (($previousException instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception\TargetNotFoundException) || ($previousException instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception\InvalidSourceException))) {
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit($this->entityNotFoundMessage);
            }
            throw $exception;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @override \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
     */
    protected function callActionMethod() {
        try {
            parent::callActionMethod();
        }
        catch(\Exception $exception) {
            // This enables you to trigger the call of TYPO3s page-not-found handler by throwing \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException
            if ($exception instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException) {
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit($this->entityNotFoundMessage);
            }

            // $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit has not been called, so the exception is of unknown type.
            \VendorName\ExtensionName\Logger\ExceptionLogger::log($exception, $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey(), \VendorName\ExtensionName\Logger\ExceptionLogger::SEVERITY_FATAL_ERROR);
            // If the plugin is configured to do so, we call the page-unavailable handler.
            if (isset($this->settings['usePageUnavailableHandler']) && $this->settings['usePageUnavailableHandler']) {
                $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageUnavailableAndExit($this->unknownErrorMessage, 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
            }
            // Else we append the error message to the response. This causes the error message to be displayed inside the normal page layout. WARNING: the plugins output may gets cached.
            if ($this->response instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Response) {
                $this->response->setStatus(500);
            }
            $this->response->appendContent($this->unknownErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an article that explains that.
However like most of articles about TYPO3 Programming is in German ;-)

http://nerdcenter.de/extbase-fehlerbehandlung/

Comment: Thanks. It would probably be useful if you could include the actual solution from the link in your answer, especially if the article is not english. As a hint for the future, you should always try to post the relevant information from an external source along with the link, to make your answer more useful.

Comment: Also, I tried your way, using `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit('Invalid data');`. But it still doesn't result in the behavior I expected. Check out the edit to my question for what I would expect to happen when throwing an exception.

Comment: That is probably because you are using the TYPO3 in production mode and not in the development mode. You must checkup your htaccess how to do so.Here you can find how to edit your .htaccess to trigger development mode.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/DevelopmentContext/Index.html

Comment: In the LocalConfiguration, I enabled debugging both for the frontend and backend. That seems to work, since a regular syntax error in the extension gets displayed just like in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you try to add that to your .htaccess file and clear your whole cache and try again, should work normally.

Comment: Check this out how to properly enable exception handling and development mode in TYPO3
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Configuration/Extending/Index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117900/discussion-between-elvis-tavasja-and-lars-ebert).